# Azure functions fail when creating a blank/empty project in an existing solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1 and am having issues creating an Azure function project. The project I am trying to create is through the template wizard, just a new V1 empty function project.

I receive the following error, which seems to be .net core related.

> NETSDK1004    Assets file '\obj\project.assets.json' not
>   found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this
>   file. FunctionApp1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    198
>   Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

But my project file states:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Just to be clear, I do want a 4.6.1 project, not a core one.

I have looked at other answers to this issue but none resolve it. Package reinstall, dotnet restore etc. I get more errors if I select a different template (e.g. HTTP Trigger)

Any ideas?

I thought I had a solution to reboot, then open %temp% and delete all the temporary files in that folder. Then reboot again for good measure and it worked from a blank / empty project, but as soon as I try include this in another solution or move the project it fails.

Comment: Not entirely sure if it's related, but there were [breaking changes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-functions-runtime-2-0-breaking-change-notice/) released on Friday. Might be affecting this?

Comment: @SubjectiveKirby Quite likely, but I am trying to deal with a vanilla 1.0 project created from scratch - seems if you copy-paste a functions project to a different location on your drive it also loses context - I think some paths may not be relative in the current config - which is going to be a nightmare. Not the Monday I was hoping for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I have it working now and I'll leave this here in case anyone else has the same.

I did try many many things to resolve, but I believe the crux of my fix was to reboot, then open `%temp%` and delete all the temporary files in that folder. Then I rebooted again for good measure and it worked from a blank / empty project.

Answer (score 0):

Well that wasted a chunk of my day. I had created a repo in git which had a space in the name. When cloned I ended up with an encoded view of the repo - i.e. a %20 for the space, which appeared in the folder path. Since this was just some demo work I had left it as is instead of tidying it up to a clean namespace.

Turns out if you have a %20 or some other encoded value in your path you will get the NETSDK1004 error. I hope this answer saves someone else some time!